# SQL Syntax Error - creating new database

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

Here's my code, currently got an error at line 3 on the USE statement :

```
 CREATE DATABASE `jamestennisdbTest`;

 USE jamestennisdbTest;

  DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lessontbl;
  CREATE TABLE lessontbl (
  LessonID int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  LessonName varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  LengthOfLesson int(11) NOT NULL,
  NoOfPupils int(11) NOT NULL,
  LocationID int(11) NOT NULL,
  `Type` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  CostPerPupil float NOT NULL,
  TotalCost float NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (LessonID),
  UNIQUE KEY LessonID_UNIQUE (LessonID),
  KEY `fk_Location_lesson-location` (LocationID),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_Location_lesson-location` FOREIGN KEY (LocationID) REFERENCES         locationstbl (LocationID) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE NO ACTION
)
```

..it goes on but thats not where the errors coming up

..And I am trying to do this through a Delphi ADOQuery (though I dont think that's where the error is)

Comment: I don't think ado query allows you to create a table, but could be wrong...

Comment: Why the 'delphi' tag? Please try this with a client application like HeidiSQL or MySQL workbench, that way you can make sure your syntax is correct.

Comment: I removed the Delphi tag, as this question has nothing to do with Delphi itself. The fact you're using a Delphi `TADOQuery` is meaningless to the question asked.

Comment: Sorry, just didnt know if the ADOQuery from Delphi was causing the error :S

Answer (score 0):

I believe the 'use' statement is only used in the mysql command line client to switch to another database. If you want to "use" another database, you'll probably need to use some API call or just reconnect directly to the newly created database.

Comment: Thanks! though any idea on how? or should i just close the query after create database, then run the rest of the query as a new query?

Comment: No, unfortunately I don't have a clue how this should be done in Delphi. I assume you have a piece of code which actually makes the database connection. I suggest you start looking there.